# Enforcing unique tuple condition in Django Rest Framework Model

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, tuples

So I have a Django Rest Framework model named `Rating` I am using as so:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    rating_for = models.TextField(choices=RATING_FOR)

    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_NUMS)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("person", "event", "rating_for"),)
```

I wish to enforce a validation condition that checks that *one person cannot have more than one rating for one event*. Basically, a duplication check.

What I tried doing, as you see, was enforce a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together) because the way I thought `unique_together` works is that it forms a tuple of these values and doesn't allow duplicate tuples.

What I mean by that is that if the `hacker` id is 1, `event` id is 2 and `rating_for` is 'food event', it (figuratively) forms a tuple `12food_event` and disallows this particular `12food_event` combination to be used. This would allow a `12networking_event`.

Apparently, this is not the way `unique_together` works. If I have a combination `12food_event` , I cannot use `food_event` with anything else in the future, same for `1` and `2`.

Is there any way of enforcing tuple uniqueness at the Model level or will I have to run a separate validation check in the serializer/view?

Answer (score 0):

You better use **UniqueTogetherValidator** or **validate()** method inside the serializers.py file. For more details, please refer the link http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/